# What does „fecerunt pedes“ mean in Latin inscriptions?

Tags: idiom, abbreviations, inscription

I have found several inscriptions in Latin that include the phrase „fecerunt/fecit pedes“

E.g. in the [Basilica Sant‘Eufemia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Cathedral_of_St_Eufemia_(Grado)_-_Mosaics) in Grado, Italy:

> Martini/anus et Simplicia / cum fili/is suis / f(ecerunt) p(edes) C

([image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Grado_St.Eufemia_-_Mosaik_6_Stifterinschrift.jpg))

In this inscription, fecerunt pedes is abbreviated as f. p.
In the same Basilica, there’s also an inscription without these abbreviations that says:

> Honora/tus cum / suis fe/cet pe/des XXV*

Both of these appear to be Founder‘s inscriptions. I would translate the first one as “Martinianus and Simplicia made the/ these feet with their sons“. However, that doesn’t make any sense as there is no relation with feet at the place of the inscription.
Therefore, I‘d like to know if there is any additional meaning to the word pes, or another possible translation.
On a side note: I don’t really understand why the second inscription says “Honoratus (…) *fecet* pedes“, when it should be (as far as I know) “…*fecit* pedes“

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In afraid you shouldn't have glossed over the numerals so easily. The first inscription does not, in fact, say

> M. and S. made the/these feet

but in fact:

> M. and S. made 100 feet

The foot was used as a unit of length in former times (among certain primitive peoples it still is), so it stands to reason that this inscription says a certain stretch of the building, 100 feet in length, was made by the people mentioned. Often *fecit* refers to the artist or craftsman who really made something, but in this case it is probably fair to assume they simply donated the necessary funds. The idea of a family with children physically building a stretch of a church, but no more, seems unrealistic.

How long a foot would be exactly is difficult to say, but the ancient Roman foot, judging by several standards that have been preserved, was around 30 cm.

Comment: I found a few sources (including [this one](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41036756)) that think this refers to *square* feet, generally of a mosaic. I'm not sure if that's universal, but it makes more sense to me than talking about length.

Comment: 'among certain primitive peoples it still is', hahaha, I'd +1'd just for that

Comment: @brianpck True, it does appear to refer to mosaic area, so it should probably be read as "square feet". Here are the mosaics from Grado: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Cathedral_of_St_Eufemia_(Grado)_-_Mosaics

Comment: I'd say the fact that he said "and sons" instead of "and children", potentially excluding any daughters adds weight to the probability that a man and his grown sons did in fact build that section, which is a model established in the Bible in Nehemiah 3: https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Nehemiah-Chapter-3/ And funnily enough it even mentions where one man did the work with his daughters, perhaps indicating an assumption that the sons always helped with all the others. So what is "unrealistic" by today's communities standards is probably not a good yard stick. We live in degenerate times.

Comment: If the width was standard, its possible that "100 feet" means "100 feet x the standard width". I know that in Guernsey greenhouses were measured this way: "100 feet of glass" meant a greenhouse 100 feet long by a locally standard width (33 ft IIRC)

Comment: @NeilG Interestingly, while *filii* technically means "sons," it is sometimes used for children in general; and the ablative plural *filiis* used here is ambiguous and could just straight away mean "daughters" anyway. I should add that contracting out the work of decorating churches to professional artisans gave us some of the very finest art in Christendom and does not seem particularly unmanly to me. In any event, the [website of the city of Grado](https://grado.it/en/what-to-do/art-history-and-culture/basilica-of-santeufemia/) says "inscriptions commemorating the benefactors."

Comment: Wait... the Romans were "primitive"?!

Comment: There are missing comments it seems @LarsH (I don't criticise, I've thought better of my words at times and deleted them since) which I'm guessing from the use of "still is" referred to a modern people, perhaps still using the foot as a measure. That is a slur on a definitely previous great people and the state of their nation today no longer reflects on the people since the nation they live in is no longer theirs. I don't think anyone here  would even remotely imply the Roman Empire was primitive, even when (or especially when) compared to modern times.

Comment: @NeilG You're right, Sebastian referred to a modern people (e.g. Americans). I was responding to his joke by jokingly pointing out that if using the foot as a unit of length meant people were primitive (as his comment suggested), then that would imply that the Romans were primitive too. (Same could be said of the Greeks and many others.)

Comment: +1 for the Americans @LarsH but not necessarily for America